# SQL Selecting from a value from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `code` = 15510642
```

I want to modify so that it checks another table as well, so for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`,`table2` WHERE `code` = 15510642
```

However that doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: what doesn't work ? Do you get too many records or an error message or ? to give an answer you need to tell more about your table structure...

Comment: if you are getting error then cause may be these both tables have code as one of the column.

Comment: I want to search both tables to see if the code exists in either of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the poster means `UNION` because he wants results from both tables?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `code` = 15510642
UNION [ALL]
SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `code` = 15510642
```

Works only when both tables contains same column (or specify them instead `*`)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[ALL] SELECT * FROM .......

Comment: `[ALL]` means, that ALL is optional. Without this option SQL returns a result without duplicates (DISTINCT), with given ALL you really get all results

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to join the tables if there's a relation between them.

```
select * from table as t1, table2 as t2 where t1.code = 15510642 or t2.code=15510642
and t1.id = t2.foreignkeyid
```

If there's no relation you could try a union, but the fields must match. So only use fields from both tables that match.

```
select id, somefield, somefield2 from table1 where code = 15510642
union
select id, somefield, somefield2 from table2 where code = 15510642
```

Answer (score 0):

Work with an [inner join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

It will be something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table t INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t.Code = t2.Code
WHERE t.Code = 15510642
```

I hope this helps!

Tjeu